# NodeJS Sequelize - delete with nested select query

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a SQL query like :

```
delete from myTable where versionId in (select id from version where code='TEST')
```

A select query nested inside a delete query. I would like to build the same query using NodeJS Sequelize, so the code could be something like this :

```
db.myTable.destroy({
        where: {
          versionId: { $in: [12, 34, 56] }
        }
    }).then(nbDeleted => {
        ...
    }
```

In that example, [12, 34, 56] is hard coded, but instead of it, I would like to use the select query.

I tried to googled in that way, but for now I'm not able to find the solution.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is a [literal](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal). Try this:

```
db.myTable.destroy({
    where: {
      versionId: { 
        $in: [
          sequelize.literal("select id from version where code='TEST'")
        ] 
      }
    }
}).then(nbDeleted => {
    ...
}
```

Sequelize will just put that literal straight into your where-in clause without any processing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in that way, "without any processing", it coud be an issue with a SQL injection since 'TEST' must be a parameter ?

Comment: Is the value 'TEST' going to be something that's sent from the user? If so, you're right, you need to sanitise it. If not, then SQL injection won't be an issue - unless you plan on staging an attack by yourself, on yourself!

What's the real context around your problem? What table are you deleting from? Where does the value 'TEST' come from in practice?

Comment: After checking, the parameter will never be send by the user, so I don't need to sanitise it. Thx again.